# convert event dates to time-event columns for survival analysis

Tags: r, transform, survival

I am trying to convert a list of observation for censored data to a proper format for survival analysis in R.
To give an exemple, the code should transform like this.

```
 event.6mo event.12mo event.24mo
1         0          0          0
2         0          1         NA
3         0          0          1
```

where each line describes a patient, 0= no event at that time point, 1=event and columns refer to 6, 12, 24 months observations.

and transform to:

```
  event censored
1    24    0
2    12    1
3    24    1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question? This reads like a code request for free. Please post your earnest attempt at a solution so we can help with specific issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `colSums` with `stack`, i.e.

```
stack(colSums(d3, na.rm = TRUE))
#  values        ind
#1      0  event.6mo
#2      1 event.12mo
#3      1 event.24mo
```

**DATA**

```
dput(d3)
structure(list(vent.6mo = c(0L, 0L, 0L), event.12mo = c(0L, 1L, 
0L), event.24mo = c(0L, NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `tidyverse`, where we pivot to 'long' format, then grouped by the 'name' get the `sum` of 'value' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(d3, everything()) %>%
   group_by(name) %>% 
   summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  name       value
#  <chr>      <int>
#1 event.12mo     1
#2 event.24mo     1
#3 vent.6mo       0
```

---

Or it can be also done by first getting the `sum` of all columns with `summarise_all` and then reshape to 'long' format

```
d3 %>%
   summarise_all(sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
   pivot_longer(everything())
```

#### data

```
d3 <- structure(list(vent.6mo = c(0L, 0L, 0L), event.12mo = c(0L, 1L, 
0L), event.24mo = c(0L, NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```